# Indenting text according to the most recent header level

Tags: html, css

My goal is to indent text based on the last header level encountered, specified here with classes, "h1-block" "h2-block" and "h3-block."

The HTML is autogenerated by code that is GFE, and cannot be altered. *The only control that I have is over the CSS.*

If the code looked like this it would be easy.

```
<div class="h1-block">
   <div class="header-1">My Header Text</div>
   Line 1 of text in the block.
   Line 2 of text in the block.
</div>
```

But that is not the case. There is no container for the block as a whole. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="header-1">My Header Text</div>
<div class="cm-line">Line 1 of text in the block.</div>
<div class="cm-line">Line 2 of text in the block.</div>
```

If anyone has suggestions I would love to hear them!

---

I appreciate the suggestion about using combinators, but I wasn't specific enough.  The difficulty involves changing indentation or margin depending on the most recently encountered level.

My goal is output that looks like:

```
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Some text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
    Text under level 2
    More text
HEADER LEVEL 1
Text under level 1
More text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
    Text under level 2
    More text
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Text under level 3
        More text
```

Getting the header indents is straightforward:

```
div.h1-block { padding-left: 0px; }
div.h2-block { padding-left: 50px; }
div.h3-block { padding-left: 100px; }
```

Then if I want text after a div.h2-block to be indented I can then add something like:

```
div.h2-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 50px; }
```

which gets me something like this -- once an h2-block is hit the indentation sticks:

```
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Some text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
    Text under level 2
    More text
HEADER LEVEL 1
    Text under level 1
    More text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
    Text under level 2
    More text
        HEADER LEVEL 3
    Text under level 3
    More text
```

That is a step in a good direction.  But now I want the text under Headers 1 and 2 to go where it belongs.  So I do:

```
div.h3-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h2-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h2-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h1-block ~ *:not(div.h2-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 0px; }
```

which gets me something like:

```
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Some text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
    Text under level 2
    More text
HEADER LEVEL 1
Text under level 1
More text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
Text under level 2
More text
        HEADER LEVEL 3
Text under level 3
More text
```

Once the last of the combinators is triggered, the previous combinators are dead.

---

One more note.  The order of the combinators matters.  If I reverse their order:

```
div.h1-block ~ *:not(div.h2-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 0px; }
div.h2-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h3-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h2-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
```

This gives:

```
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Some text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
        Text under level 2
        More text
HEADER LEVEL 1
        Text under level 1
        More text
    HEADER LEVEL 2
        Text under level 2
        More text
        HEADER LEVEL 3
        Text under level 3
        More text
```

I thought, OK, so it goes through the CSS until it finds a matching case. So I tried:

```
div.h3-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h2-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h2-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h1-block ~ *:not(div.h2-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 0px; }
div.h3-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h2-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h2-block ~ *:not(div.h1-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 20px; }
div.h1-block ~ *:not(div.h2-block):not(div.h3-block) { padding-left: 0px; }
```

This gave the same result as I got with a single triplet of combinators. That is perhaps not surprising since an identical statement just replaces the earlier version in the hierarchy.

So... Thoughts?  Is there a way around this that I'm missing?

Comment: No mention of h1, h2, h3 in your examples...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the adjacent sibling combinator perhaps? Your question makes no mention of how you can control the CSS, but assuming that it's in a CSS file or style tag this solution should work.

HTML

```
<div class="header-1">My Header Text</div>
<div class="cm-line">Line 1 of text in the block.</div>
<div class="cm-line">Line 2 of text in the block.</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-1 + .cm-line { 
  margin-left: 8px; // or whatever your indent is. 
}
```

The key here is that you use the `+` symbol. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: Thanks. Using combinators is a good direction.  But I wasn't clear enough in my original post.  If you like take a look at the modified version above.